# Linked list: get node by index has unexpected results

Tags: c, indexing, linked-list

This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _node {
    int data;
    struct _node* next;
} llnode;

llnode* llgetindex(llnode** header, int index){
    if(*header == NULL) return NULL;
    llnode* i = *header;
    llnode* j = *header;
    if(index < 0){
        // negative indexes
        while(index < 0){
            if(i == NULL) return NULL;
            i = i->next;
            index++;
        }
        while(i != NULL){
            i = i->next;
            j = j->next;
        }
        return j;
    } else {
        //positive indexes
        while(index > 0){
            if(i == NULL) return NULL;
            i=i->next;
            index--;
        }
        return i;
    }
}

llnode* push(llnode** header, int data){
    if(*header == NULL) {
        llnode* item =  malloc(sizeof(llnode));
        item->data = data;
        item->next = NULL;
        *header = item;
        return item;
    } else {
        llnode* item = llgetindex(header, (-1));
        item->next = malloc(sizeof(llnode));
        item->next->data = data;
        item->next->next = NULL; 
        return item->next;
    }
}

llnode* pop(llnode** header){
    if(*header == NULL) return NULL;
    llnode* last = NULL;
    // if list is one item long
    if((*header)->next == NULL){
        last = *header;
        *header = NULL;
        
    } else {
        llnode* blast = llgetindex(header,(-2));
        printf("[0]%lli\n",*header);
        printf("[1]%lli\n",(*header)->next);
        last = blast->next;
        blast->next = NULL;
    }
    return last;
    
}
```

I've traced the problem to the function llgetindex; it somehow is overwriting the pointer to the first element of the list and changing it to what llgetindex should return when given a negative index, but i don't get how.
The strangest thing is that calling push works fine, pop doesn't and calling llgetindex directly also destroys the list.
If you can explain why it happens i would be happy.

To reproduce the problem:
create a llnode** pointer and call `push` function a few times to populate the list, after call either `pop` or `llgetindex` using a negative index and check the list, now the first node of the list should now be either the last if you called pop, or the element indexed by the negative index given to llgetindex.

gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110

Comment: Please provide a [complete minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What you have is close - just need to provide the code that sets up the list and calls the functions in a way that reproduces the problem.

Comment: i did, but it complained about too much code and little explanation

Comment: i added instructions to reproduce the problem, hopefully that's done now.

Comment: What results are you expecting when you get a negative index?

Comment: to get the node on the absolute value of the index, but starting from the end

Comment: So is `llgetindex(header, -1)` the last element of the list? Is it `NULL`?

Comment: only if the list is empty, otherwise it should return the a pointer to the last element

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing exactly what the problem is, but if I may ask, why are you passing the head element as an `llnode **`? The only way that could be useful is to rewrite the `head` pointer, which you don't need in most of your functions.

Comment: yes, that exactly why i use double pointer, so the list can be empty, the problem is that somehow llgetindex overwrites  `*header` pointer to the node the negative index points to, but when push calls llgetindex it does not overwrite *header, idk why, i checked the code for over three days now, trying different things, they all came to the same conclusion, i'm starting to think the problem is on on another place that is not my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229916/discussion-between-dariem-fabian-hidalgo-arias-and-sam-henke).

Comment: Cannot reproduce [any issue](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcomq666305005459839)

Comment: After further testing the issue was with llgetlinked list, aparently i had to allocate both pointers for it to work, idk why, but that resolved the issue.